# Send Push notifications (Toasts) with launch parameters in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, winjs

I have a WinJS project which has a **BackgroundTask** in **Runtime Component** that triggers when Push Notification is sent (**Raw notifications**) from my own webservice.
And that Background service creates a local toasts and show it in action notification center.

```
 public static void ShowNotification(int notificationId, string ToastTitle, int messageType, string messageDetails)
    {
        string messageText = String.Empty;
        ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText04;
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
        XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");

        toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(ToastTitle));//Toast notification title
        toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(messageText));
        toastTextElements[2].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(messageDetails));

        var launchAttribute = toastXml.CreateAttribute("launch");
        IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
        ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "short");
        toastNode.Attributes.SetNamedItem(launchAttribute);

        //Launch params
        var toastNavigationUriString = messageDetails;
        var toastElement = ((XmlElement)toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast"));
        toastElement.SetAttribute("launch", toastNavigationUriString);

        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
        toast.Tag = notificationId.ToString();
        toast.ExpirationTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(3);

        if (true)
        {
            toast.SuppressPopup = false;//to send notification directly to action center without displaying a popup on phone.
        }

        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
    }
```

And I was handling those toasts like this in JS:

```
WinJS.Application.addEventListener("activated", onActivatedHandler, true);

function onActivatedHandler(args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        messageDetails = args.detail.arguments;
        PhonegapService.setNotificationMessage(messageDetails, function () {
            window.location.href = "index.html";
        });
    }
}
```

**XML** format that is used in this case on my webservice is:

```
string rawMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<root>" +
                "<Value1>" + "Hello" + "<Value1>" +
                "<Value2>" + "Raw" + "<Value2>" +
            "</root>";
```

Now there is slightly change in Push Notifications. I want to send push notifications (**Toasts**) directly from my webservice rather than sending Raw messages.

My questions are:

1. How to attach `launch` params and `message` on my toast notification in web-service similar like we did while creating local toasts.
2. When toasts are received how to handle click events and get the useful messages attached with that notification.

**XML** in this case would be like this:

```
string toast1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> ";

           string toast2 = string.Format(@"<toast>
                       <visual>
                           <binding template=""ToastText04"">
                               <text id=""1"">{0}</text>
                               <launch></launch>
                           </binding>
                       </visual>
                   </toast>",message);
           string xml = toast1 + toast2;
```

**Update 1**

I used the following XML on my web-service. But I'm getting notification in an unusual format than I expected:

```
 string toast1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> ";
 string message = "some json";
                string toast2 = string.Format(@"<toast launch= ""{0}"">
                         <visual version=""1"">
                             <binding template=""ToastText02"">
                                 <text id=""1"">{1}</text>
                                   <text id=""2"">{2}</text>
                             </binding>
                         </visual>
                     </toast>", message, "Alert", "Test");
```

Comment: You have double quotes *"" ""* instead of a single character quote. If you are using @, you can use single quotes: *'*

Comment: Oh I noticed that. But my json is something like this: `"{\\\"Message\\\":{\\\"ActionId\\\":\\\"6724d22a-87878789fe-4137-b501-9d9a9a078558b1\\\",\\\"ActionDetailId\\\":\\\"dc02e878784-7832-4625-a538-29be9807f885ccb\\\",\\\"Calamity\\\":\\\"Calamity  helo\\\",\\\"UserName\\\":null,\\\"ActionDateTime\\\":\\\"2015-09-15T15:36:14+05:45\\\",\\\"CalamityId\\\":\\\"c0fa848e-ee6c-4b91-8391-a12058f25387\\\",\\\"Calls\\\":true,\\\"IsActionCompleted\\\":false},\\\"Type\\\":\\\"Calamity\\\"}"`

Comment: OK, this is now out of scope for this question, but your json is invalid. Replace every /// with just a single /

Comment: Wow thanks for everything. It worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an XML with the same structure as the following (with or without the custom audio):

```
<toast launch=\"$param\">
   <audio src=\"ms-appx:///Assets/Sounds/$sound.wav\"/>
   <visual>
       <binding template=\"ToastText04\">
           <text id=\"1\">$title</text>
           <text id=\"2\">$msg</text>
       </binding>
   </visual>
</toast>
```

Notice that `launch` is a member of the `<toast>` tag.

You can handle click events the same as before when the app is activated, you get the string that is the value of `launch`.

Comment: I'm bit confused. Do I have to do this in my web service?

Comment: Sorry, yes you have to send this xml with your web service.

Comment: Please see the edit in my question. I have added an update 1 to my question. I used as you said but I get toasts in an unusual format.  Is there anything wrong? Please have a look.